# This range is repeated, or values overlap: C811-C811

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset called drug with two variables code and short_description.

The type of code variable is $5 and type of short_description variable is $25.

I would like to convert this SAS dataset to format by using the following code:

```
data work.drug_route;

   set library.drug;

   length fmtname $32.;

   retain fmtname '$drug_description';

   rename code=start;

   rename short_description = label;
run;


proc format library= library.formats cntlin=work.drug_route;
run;
```

Does anyone who have experience dealing with such kind of issue?

Much appreciated!

Comment: [link] the link to the related question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126104/sas-formatserror-for-format-countries-this-range-is-repeated-or-values-over

Comment: Does `C811` appear as the `code` on more than one data row?  What happens if you run `proc sort data=drug_route out=drug_nodup nodupkey; by start; run;` - does that return the exact same dataset back, or does it remove some rows?

Comment: yes, there are duplicate code rows. I deduped that and fixed this! Thank you so much!