# SAS proc import then proc format: ERROR: For format $xxxxx, this range is repeated, or values overlap: C4311-C4311

Tags: sas

I am a SAS novice and I have encountered this issue. I already referred to several posts including this: [[SAS Formats]ERROR: For format COUNTRIES, this range is repeated, or values overlap: .-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126104/sas-formatserror-for-format-countries-this-range-is-repeated-or-values-over).

I used following code block to export a particular entry  (Ias1012324y22y23mc) in my SAS catalog

```
libname perm '<path>';
filename tempfile '<filename>.csv' ;

proc FORMAT FMTLIB LIB=formats.formats cntlout=sasuser.fmtdata;
        select $Ias1012324y22y23mc;
    run;

proc export data=sasuser.fmtdata outfile=tempfile dbms=csv replace;
run;

quit;
```

My intention is to make a few changes and import into a different catalog but I needed to verify so I am uploading the exact same csv file but I still ran into this issue:

```
ERROR: For format $IAS1012324Y22Y23MC, this range is repeated, or values overlap: C4311-C4311
```

Here is my import script:

```
libname perm '<path>';
filename tempfile '<filename>.csv' ;

PROC IMPORT
    datafile=tempfile OUT=updated DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
    GETNAMES=YES; 
RUN;

proc format library=perm.library fmtlib cntlin=updated;
    select $IAS1012324Y22Y23MC;  
 run;

quit;
```

I also tried to add a controlset with no luck as mentioned here: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n03qskwoints2an1ispy57plwrn9.htm

```
PROC IMPORT
    datafile=tempfile OUT=updated DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
    GETNAMES=YES; 
RUN;

data ctrl;
    retain fmtname '$IAS1012324Y22Y23MC';   
    length FMTNAME $32. START $9. END $9. LABEL $23. PREFIX $2. FILL $1. TYPE $1. SEXCL $1. EEXCL $1. HLO $13. DECSEP $1. DIG3SEP $1. DATATYPE $8. LANGUAGE $8.;        
    set updated;    
    * proc print;
run;


proc format library=perm.library fmtlib cntlin=ctrl;
select $IAS1012324Y22Y23MC;  
run;

quit;
```

Here is my dataset where the overlap is happening

```
FMTNAME,START,END,LABEL,MIN,MAX,DEFAULT,LENGTH,FUZZ,PREFIX,MULT,FILL,NOEDIT,TYPE,SEXCL,EEXCL,HLO,DECSEP,DIG3SEP,DATATYPE,LANGUAGE
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C4310,C4310,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C43111,C43111,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C43112,C43112,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C43121,C43121,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C43122,C43122,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
IAS1012324Y22Y23MC,C4320,C4320,23,1,40,4,4,0,,0,,0,C,N,N,,,,,
```

Clearly the issue seems to be default value range for START when I import the data it came with 4, I edited the csv file and changed default column to 9 but still the same issue.

### Update

Here is the generated data step after adding GUESSINGROWS=MAX; still the same issue.

```
data WORK.UPDATED    ;
%let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
infile 'F:\SAS Programs\RAF2024InitialModel\import-model-sg\data-in-ascii.txt' delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=13106 firstobs=2 ;
informat FMTNAME $18. ;
informat START $9. ;
informat END $9. ;
informat LABEL best32. ;
informat MIN best32. ;
informat MAX best32. ;
informat DEFAULT best32. ;
informat LENGTH best32. ;
informat FUZZ best32. ;
informat PREFIX $1. ;
informat MULT best32. ;
informat FILL $1. ;
informat NOEDIT best32. ;
informat TYPE $1. ;
informat SEXCL $1. ;
informat EEXCL $1. ;
informat HLO $1. ;
informat DECSEP $1. ;
informat DIG3SEP $1. ;
informat DATATYPE $1. ;
informat LANGUAGE $1. ;
format FMTNAME $18. ;
format START $9. ;
format END $9. ;
format LABEL best12. ;
format MIN best12. ;
format MAX best12. ;
format DEFAULT best12. ;
format LENGTH best12. ;
format FUZZ best12. ;
format PREFIX $1. ;
format MULT best12. ;
format FILL $1. ;
format NOEDIT best12. ;
format TYPE $1. ;
format SEXCL $1. ;
format EEXCL $1. ;
format HLO $1. ;
format DECSEP $1. ;
format DIG3SEP $1. ;
format DATATYPE $1. ;
format LANGUAGE $1. ;
input
            FMTNAME  $
            START  $
            END  $
            LABEL
            MIN
            MAX
            DEFAULT
            LENGTH
            FUZZ
            PREFIX  $
            MULT
            FILL  $
            NOEDIT
            TYPE  $
            SEXCL  $
            EEXCL  $
            HLO  $
            DECSEP  $
            DIG3SEP  $
            DATATYPE  $
            LANGUAGE  $
;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

Comment: So your main mistake it probably the use of PROC IMPORT to read a text file.  Just write a data step to read the file instead and you can control the names, types and for character variables the lengths of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let PROC IMPORT GUESS how to read your text file. Write your own code instead.  If you do have to use PROC IMPORT to read a text file make sure to always use the GUESSINGROWS=MAX; statement so that it checks the whole file before deciding the type and length to use for each variable.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your response, adding GUESSINGROWS=MAX kicked the cursor down couple of pages, ended up with the same error at a different part of the input. could you review the generate data step (added to the original question as an update at the end). I did try to write my own dataset but my "2-day" SAS knowledge is too limited, I am a Spark/DataEngineer working an ad-hoc task as a favor.

Comment: Actually it worked, The data started with range Axxxx - Zxxxxx and then a small portion was repeating another range which I believe supposed to be a different dataset or duplicate data. Thank you so much Tom.